# quanteda kwic regex operation

Tags: r, regex, nlp, quanteda

Further **edit to original question**.
Question originated by expectation that regexes would work identically or nearly to "grep" or to some programming language. This below is what I expected and the fact that it did not happen generated my question (using cygwin):

```
echo "regex unusual operation will deport into a different" > out.txt
grep "will * dep" out.txt
"regex unusual operation will deport into a different"
```

---

*Originary question*
Trying to follow https://github.com/kbenoit/ITAUR/blob/master/README.md
to learn Quanteda after seeing that everybody that uses this package finds it very good.
In [demo.R](https://github.com/kbenoit/ITAUR/blob/master/1_demo/demo.R), line 22 I find the line:

```
kwic(immigCorpus, "deport", window = 3)
```

Its output is -

```
[BNP, 157]        The BNP will | deport | all foreigners convicted  
[BNP, 1946]                . 2. | Deport | all illegal immigrants    
[BNP, 1952] immigrants We shall | deport | all illegal immigrants  
[BNP, 2585]  Criminals We shall | deport | all criminal entrants
```

To try/learn the basics I execute

```
kwic(immigCorpus, "will *depo", window = 3, valuetype = "regex")
```

expecting to get

```
[BNP, 157]        The BNP will | deport | all foreigners convicted
```

but I get:

```
kwic object with 0 rows
```

Similar attempts like

```
kwic(immigCorpus, ".*will *depo.*", window = 3, valuetype = "regex")
```

Get the same result:

```
kwic object with 0 rows
```

Why is that? Tokenization? if so how should I write the regex?

PS Thanks for this great package

Comment: Speed and quality of answers to my beginner's question seem to me yet another important factor in favour of this package.

Comment: Just noticed this comment, which pleases us on the quanteda development team! If you would like to leave a brief testimonial, please consider doing so [here](https://github.com/quanteda/quanteda/issues/461).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to match a *phrase* with your pattern. By default, the *`pattern`* argument is treated as a space separated list of keywords, and the search is performed against this list. So, you may get your expected result using

```
> kwic(immigCorpus, phrase("will deport"), window = 3)
[BNP, 156:157] - The BNP | will deport | all foreigners convicted
```

A *`valuetype = "regex"`* makes sense if you are using a regex. E.g. to get both `shall` and `will deport` use

```
> kwic(immigCorpus, phrase("(will|shall) deport"), window = 3, valuetype = "regex")

   [BNP, 156:157]             - The BNP | will deport  | all foreigners convicted
 [BNP, 1951:1952] illegal immigrants We | shall deport | all illegal immigrants  
 [BNP, 2584:2585]  Foreign Criminals We | shall deport | all criminal entrants
```

See [this `kwic` documentation](https://github.com/quanteda/quanteda/blob/master/docs/reference/kwic.html).

Answer (score 0):

The examples from the ITAUR repository are based on an older syntax.  What you need is the `phrase()` wrapper - see `?phrase`.  You should also probably brush up on the regular expression syntax you are trying to achieve with the `*`, since it may not be what you want, and since a regular expression cannot start with a "*".  ([This](https://blog.mariusschulz.com/2014/06/03/why-using-in-regular-expressions-is-almost-never-what-you-actually-want) might help.)  The default "glob" valuetype will probably achieve what you want.

```
library("quanteda")
## Package version: 1.1.4
## Parallel computing: 2 of 8 threads used.
## See https://quanteda.io for tutorials and examples.

kwic(data_char_ukimmig2010, phrase("will deport"))

## [BNP, 156:157] nation.- The BNP | will deport | all foreigners convicted of crimes

kwic(data_char_ukimmig2010, phrase("will .*deport.*"), valuetype = "regex")

## [BNP, 156:157] nation.- The BNP | will deport | all foreigners convicted of crimes
```

Comment: Thanks. PS I am not aware of regexes in my code starting with "*" 
I use " *" that I believe to match zero or more spaces, and ".*" that I expect to match zero or more characters.

Comment: Any pattern that contains a white space assumes you are trying to match that literal token, so in your example, `"will *depo"` will match tokens `"willdepo"`, or `"will     depo"`, which may not be what you expected. `phrase("will *depo")` produces an error since it splits the sequence into two regexes, and the second will start with `*`.