# Construct a character vector of multi-word phrases using regex for building dfm using quanteda in R

Tags: r, regex, quanteda

I've used to great satisfaction quanteda's textstat_collocation() for extracting MWE. Now I'm trying to extract all matches that match a specific pattern, irrespective of their frequency.

My objective is to create a character vector by extracting featnames from a dfm() built with a regex pattern. I will then use this character vector in the "select" argument for building a dfm. I might also want to use this character vector to add to a dictionary I use as an ontology for building dfms at later stages of the pipeline.

The pattern is: "aged xx-xx" where x is a digit.

I used the regex pattern "aged\s([0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2})" [here](https://regexr.com/3pnpc) and got the desired matches. But when I try it in R (adding an additional "\" before "\s"), I don't get any matches.

When I do:

```
txt <- c("In India, male smokers aged 20-45 perceive brandX positively.",
              "In Spain, female buyers aged 30-39 don't purchase brandY.")
ageGroups <- dfm(txt, select = "aged\\s([0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2})", valuetype = "regex")
featnames(ageGroups)
```

I get:

```
character(0)
```

However, when I try:

```
ageGroups <- dfm(txt, select = "([0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2})", valuetype = "regex")
featnames(ageGroups)
```

I get:

```
[1] "20-45" "30-39"
```

It seems I'm unable to capture the white space in the regex. I've gone through many similar questions in SO, with perhaps [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36732659/r-construct-document-term-matrix-how-to-match-dictionaries-whose-values-consist) being the most relevant, but still can't get to make my specific objective to work.

I also tried:

```
tokens <- tokens(txt, remove_punct = FALSE, remove_numbers = FALSE, remove_symbols = FALSE)
tokensCompunded <- tokens_compound(tokens, pattern =  "aged\\s([0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2})", valuetype = "regex")
attr(tokensCompunded, "types")
```

But I get all tokens back:

```
[1] "In"         " "          "India"      ","          "male"       "smokers"    "aged"       "20-45"      "perceive"  
[10] "brandX"     "positively" "."          "Spain"      "female"     "buyers"     "30-39"      "don't"      "purchase"  
[19] "brandY"
```

I think there might be several other more efficient approaches for extracting character vectors using regex (or glob) with quanteda, and I'm happy to learn new ways how to use this amazing R package.

Thanks for your help!

**Edit to original question:**

*[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49478723/quanteda-kwic-regex-operation) other question in SO has a similar requirement, i.e. detecting multi-word phrases using kwic objects, and can be further expanded to achieve the objectives stated above with the following addition:*

```
kwicObject <- kwic(corpus, pattern = phrase("aged ([0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2})"), valuetype = "regex")
unique(kwicObject$keyword)
```

Comment: Thanks Wiktor! When I use 'pattern = phrase("aged\\s+([0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2})")' for creating a kwic object, I get "kwic object with 0 rows". I also tried it with tokens_select() and tokens_compound() and got "character(0)" when attr(x, "type"). However, Ken's "aged [0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}" does work too for creating kwic objects with multi-word phrases.

Comment: I think this question should be reopened, since it's not an _exact_ duplicate. Also seems a bit ungallant to close questions that might compete with the closer's other answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that the target text and the multi-word `pattern` (which contains white space) are not being tokenised the same way.  In your example, you have applied a regex for multiple tokens (which includes the whitespace separator) but the target for search has already been split into individual tokens.

We devised a solution to this, a function called `phrase()`.  From `?pattern`:

> Whitespace is not privileged, so that in a character vector, white
>   space is interpreted literally. If you wish to consider
>   whitespace-separated elements as sequences of tokens, wrap the
>   argument in `phrase()`.

So in this case:

```
pat <- "aged [0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}"

toks2 <- tokens_select(toks, pattern = phrase(pat), valuetype = "regex")
toks2
# tokens from 2 documents.
# text1 :
# [1] "aged"  "20-45"
# 
# text2 :
# [1] "aged"  "30-39"
```

Here, we see that the selection worked, because the `phrase()` wrapper converted the pattern into a sequence of matches.

If you want to make these a single token, you can send the same `pattern` argument to `tokens_compound()`:

```
toks3 <- tokens_compound(toks2, pattern = phrase(pat), 
                         valuetype = "regex", concatenator = " ")
toks3
# tokens from 2 documents.
# text1 :
# [1] "aged 20-45"
# 
# text2 :
# [1] "aged 30-39"
```

Finally, you can use that to construct a dfm, where each multi-word match is a feature.  This cannot work unless you have first performed the concatenation at the tokens stage, since by definition a dfm has no order in its features.

```
dfm(toks3)
# Document-feature matrix of: 2 documents, 2 features (50% sparse).
# 2 x 2 sparse Matrix of class "dfm"
#        features
# docs    aged 20-45 aged 30-39
#   text1          1          0
#   text2          0          1
```

Comment: This approach solved my requirement perfectly. Thanks Ken.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the regex pattern:

```
select = "aged.*([0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2})"
```

Comment: Please explain how this regex solves the OP problem.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! While this answer is probably correct and useful, it is preferred if you include some explanation along with it to explain how it helps to solve the problem. This becomes especially useful in the future, if there is a change (possibly unrelated) that causes it to stop working and users need to understand how it once worked.